# Circumventing resource exhaustion errors when solving systems of equations using CX CAS

Tags: variables, calculator, equation, equation-solving, ti-nspire

I am attempting to solve the following system of 2 equations (2 unknowns) using a Ti-Nspire CX CAS calculator:

[image]

[image]

I have already solved it using Mathematica:

```
Solve[v*Sqrt[1+0.5^2 + 2*0.5*Cos[2*(2*Pi/(8*10^-3))*(-3*10^-3) + p]]==2 && v*Sqrt[1+0.5^2 + 2*0.5*Cos[2*(2*Pi/(8*10^-3))*(-1*10^-3) + p]]==6 && 0<=p<=2*Pi, {v,p}];
```

So I know that v=4 and p=Pi/2 but I get a "Resource exhaustion; Cannot complete calculation" error when I try to solve the system on the calculator with the following 3 steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you insert constrains within solve command instead when defining functions:

```
solve(l(p,v)=2 and u(p,v)=6 and 0≤p and p≤2*π,{p,v})
```

answer: v=4. and p=1.5707964860087
Also use expressions instead of functions, unless you have very good reason for, like:

```
u:=v*√(1+(0.5)^(2)+2*0.5*cos(((2*−0.001*2*π)/(0.008))+p))
l:=v*√(1+(0.5)^(2)+2*0.5*cos(((2*−0.003*2*π)/(0.008))+p))
```

solve command and result are the same as above.
Of course, in this case solve will find the correct solution without any constrains:

```
solve(l=2 and u=6,{p,v})
```

answer: v=4. and p=1.5707964860087
But it wont find any other solutions, and for some reason this doesnt work for the solution between 2*π and 4*π

```
solve(l=2 and u=6 and 2*π≤p and p≤4*π,{p,v})
```

In that case, you can use zeros

```
zeros({l-2,u-6},{p,v})|2*π≤p and p≤4*π
```

answer: [[7.8539817931882,4.]]